# Best Practice: Authentication between Silverlight Client and a.Net Server

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication

I'm working on a Project where I run a Server that is basically a .Net C# Application with a SQL Server Express DB and will now use WCF for Webservice implementation and then there are Silverlight Clients that different Companies will use to interact with this Server. How do I implement User Authentication in a good and reliable way? I've read a lot of Posts here that will user ASP on the Server side, but my Server isn't an ASP Server. Should I implement it anyway or are there any other options?

My naive thought was something like that:

- Username, Password and Company is stored as a credential in the DB
- The Silverlight Client asks on Startup those credentials and sends them to the Server to get a confirmation.
- from now on those credentials are in every communication between Client and Server and the Server confirms them every time.

Is this to naive and insecure?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using basic web protocol, you could consider using an HTTPS channel and

1) embedding the credentials in the URL -  as long as you're using HTTPS this is OK

2) getting a unique identifier back from the service on initial validation of credentials, and then requiring this identifier in all future calls - saves on the db lookup, but you should still stay in https -  if you use http, then it's by definition insecure